# Codeigniter Search with spaces

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, sql-like

I have a search function that searchers for users in the database.

The model look like this

```
public function search_user_details($conditions){
$search = $conditions["search"];


$this->db->like('username', $search);
$this->db->or_like('first_name', $search);
$this->db->or_like('last_name', $search);
$this->db->from($this->user_table);
$this->db->select("id, first_name, last_name, username, password, email, bio, country,     avatar, cover, notes_check, verified, private, POST_SCORE, COMMENT_SCORE");
$this->db->limit(200);
$query= $this->db->get();

results = $query->result_array();
return $results;
}
```

Example, a user has the following details: first_name = Fran, last_name= Allison, username = fran.

If I search any of these her details get returned: fran, allison. 
If I search: 'Fran Allison' together nothing gets returned.
eg  $conditions["search"] ="Fran Allsion"

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: which array you pass to the model

Comment: Username contains what??

Answer (score 0):

```
public function search_user_details($conditions) {
     $search = $conditions["search"];

     $first = $search;
     $last = $search;

     // If the search contains a space, separate the two words.
     if(preg_match('/\s/', $search))
     {
          $name = explode(" ", $search);
          $first = $name[0];
          $last = $name[1];
     }

     $this->db->like('username', $search);
     $this->db->or_like('first_name', $first);
     $this->db->or_like('last_name', $last);

     // This is in case they search Lastname first. 
     $this->db->or_like('first_name', $last);
     $this->db->or_like('last_name', $first);

     $this->db->from($this->user_table);
     $this->db->select("id, first_name, last_name, username, password, email, bio, country,     avatar,      cover, notes_check, verified, private, POST_SCORE, COMMENT_SCORE");
     $this->db->limit(200);
     $query= $this->db->get();

     results = $query->result_array();
     return $results;
}
```